# Saving the result of a query to a property of a Model/Schema with Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback, mean-stack

First of all, I'm fairy new to MEAN Stack and Node.js, so go easy on me :)

I know all these kind of functions in Node.js are callback functions and are asynchronous, but since Node.js is widely used, what I think as a downside is probably not a downside at all. Let me define my problem;

Let's say you have a Schema of a user whose one field is a reference to another schema. e.g.

```
PersonSchema = {
   name: String,
   ...
   ...
   ...
   projects : [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Project',
      required: true
   }],
   ...
   ...
}
```

How do I exactly make sure that I get a particular project from database and add to the user's database with mongoose?

What I'm doing is something like:

```
var proj = Project.findOne({"name":"The Manhattan Project"})
```

Since these all happen in app.post(...) method, they eventually happen, but not necessarily when they are supposed to.

```
var newUser = new User();
newUser.name  = req.body.name;
newUser... = ...
newUser.projects = [proj.id];
...

newUser.save(callback function{})
```

When I save the new User object with this project, it gives me an error because proj is undefined (which is understandable because the query function is a callback function) buy I literally have no idea to fix this right now.

Can someone give me some idea to how to fix this, or fix my way of understanding if it's wrong, or at least push me to the right direction so I can find more resources by researching.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindOne takes a callback as its second param. You should not assign project to its return, you should just call it, then carry on your use logic inside the callback...

```
Model.findOne({ age: 5}, function (err, doc){
    // doc is a Document
    // do things that happen after a sync retrieve in here...
});
```

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. So you are suggesting me to "stack" the callback functions by calling one inside the other one to make sure they will execute in order, am I right? So I should call this: `newUser.save(callback function{})` inside this: `Project.findOne({...}, function(...){ **HERE** });`

Please let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes - that is correct. There are further techniques to avoid deeply nesting callbacks (search for pyramid of doom) but this should hopefully cover your current problem of execution order.